# Animate DIV's height to fit dynamically loaded contetent

Tags: javascript, jquery

A `DIV` which it's content (another inner `DIV`) can be changed.
I want to achieve the following effect:

1. Fade out current content.
2. Animate the height of DIV to fit the height of the new content.
3. Fade in the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WNS3B/

This is made possible using jquery and a fallback function of fadeOut method.

```
$('.one').fadeOut(function(){
    $('.p').css('height', oldH); // keeping parent from collapsing
    $('.p').animate({"height": newH});
    $('.two').delay(300).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work when the `div`s being swapped are static? I don't think this helps the dynamic part.

Comment: @user3669154 I think that you can get the height of a basic element even if it isn't in the DOM, but if it contains images etc, you are right.

Comment: I was thinking more of updating text/other content via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `delay`. you can use done callback on `animate`

```
$('.p').css('height', oldH); // keeping parent from collapsing
$('.one').fadeOut(function(){
    $('.p').animate({"height": newH},{
        done: function(){
            $('.two').fadeIn();    
        }
    });

});
})
```

see the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/WNS3B/2/